# как прочитать переданый параметр через route в ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Всем привет, я пытаюсь передать параметр something через роутинг в ReactJS вот так

```
 <Route path='/' component={L} something="foo"/>
```

Но как мне его получить в L компоненте?

```
    render() {
        return (
           <div>
               template {this.props.route.something}
       </div>

        );
    }
}
```

Он говорит что TypeError: this.props.route is undefined

Как прочитать переданый параметр?

Comment: вот откуда вы этот код взяли там ответ уже дан.Осталось чуть-чуть ниже спустится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ivan Semochkin - почти так только чуть чуть поправил и все работает спасибо

```
<Route exact path="/" render={(props) => (<L something="foo" {...props}/>)}/>
```